# How to disable private key authorization on LEMP server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, dreamweaver, putty

I run a LEMP VPS using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.  I started it with a tutorial, and am starting to learn my way around, but it had me create a private key with putty/pageant.  I can really only use Filezilla sftp for transfer and I login to the console w/ putty.  However, now I want to start working on some major changes to my website in Dreamweaver CS5 and I want to sync all my files locally but it does not support private key authorization.

My private key is located at

/USER/.ssh/authorized_keys

I tried going into nano and just deleting it but that doesn't work.. I just want to temporarily disable the requirement for private key authorization, not remove it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the `authorized_keys` file doesn't mean that you can use passwords, it means that you can't login with keys, to use passowrds you need to edit the ssh config it self,

File: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, check the bottom of the file and set this

```
UsePAM yes
```